# fast-render vs server-side rendering

Tags: meteor

I tried to look it up but there is no real comparison, just mentioning that both of these make better performance, maybe anyone knows which of those approaches are better for client and server performance?

It seems like ssr gives all the hard work to server giving plain html to client. Also, it attaches data to whole template, so every time it changes, template is resend to client?

One thing I think would be nice but I'm not sure about it, if data is sent from server are publishes still needed?

Comment: Basically, SSR is for SEO because crawlers will usually not process any javascript on their side. This is not something you would achieve with FastRender, which only makes sure that the initial dataset is sent down the wire along with your app source code.

Comment: Yea this helps a lot and is a big plus, but you can also achieve it by spiderable package, my biggest concern is performance since I want to build fast working site

Comment: google now is *supposed* to support client side rendering